# Article not following site's layout (Joomla)

Tags: joomla, width, joomla-article

please go to [www.espacioasir.com](http://www.espacioasir.com) first and notice how the second article has been 'crushed' to the left - half of the article's normal width.

Anyway, I don't think I can explain much more, my question is very clear: Why is this happening? I do want mention that the content of the article itself has nothing to do (or maybe just a bit), as I tried changing it, and the text did expand to the article's normal width; however, the bar on top (with the article's title "Espacio Asir" and the PDF, print & mail icons was still only at half-width).

I also tried changing the site back to Joomla's default theme, but this did not help. I guess it could be a Joomla 1.5 bug, but I really don't think such obvious error would be present in this version.

I'd really appreciate any help in advance, and if I did not explain myself clear enough, please let me know and I'll add the info needed and post some screens.
Chris

Comment: Add a third post and it will look OK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a feature, not a bug. If you add a third article, the third one will be on the second row, to the right of the second article, also "crushed". -- Or "1/2 column" rather than full column width.

[Information on overriding the default layout](http://docs.joomla.org/Show_Blog_Layouts_in_Table_Format). For more help, ask in the Joomla forums.

Comment: Thank you so very much, I didn't know they had such a weird feature.
In any case, as you explained those were columns, I noticed I could change the value from 2 to 1, and so I did. You can see it works perfectly now.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This how Joomla shows a blog layout. Its working properly.

http://www.joomla4web.com/blog/Front-Page-Blog-Layout.html

If you want to change the layout type, you need to go to the Main Menu, and edit the **Home** menu item. You will see that its set to blog layout. You can click on the change type button to choose a different one.

Comment: I tried changing it, but I just changed the # of columns and that did it for me. Thank you very much!